# Spring MVC default MIME type when multiple endpoints are mapped to the same path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two endpoints in a controller mapped to the same path (the controller's root path) with different MIME types.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/a+json"})
public ResponseEntity<URI> methodA() {
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/b+json"})
public ResponseEntity<URI> methodB() {
}
```

When no `Accept` header is sent with the request, the response is always of type `application/a+json`.

How is `spring-mvc` choosing that by default? After some trials, my observation is that it's being chosen based on the alphabetical order (MIME type starting with `a` vs starting with `b`), but I didn't find any documentation around that. Is that how it works?

Comment: @Eugene The response is of type `application/json` in that case, so that's indeed the one getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are seeing some order, I would advise to not rely on it.

Instead define another method that does not declare `produces`and in this way you will know **for sure** that `Accept` was not sent - instead of :

> was in sent with `application/a+json` or not sent at all.

This 3-rd method could do nothing really, it could just delegate to whatever you already have, initially logging the request for example.

Comment: I guess this is a workaround I can live with for now. What I'm actually looking for is: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14481